# NSString to NSDate conversion. Problem with "2011-08-24T14:06:10Z"

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, nsdate

How to convert that string:

```
2011-08-24T14:06:10Z
```

to NSDate using NSDateFormatter. I don´t know which format to set. What does this ´T´and ´Z´mean?

Comment: I believe 'T' is just a separator between date and time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a RFC3339 date format.

You can parse it using:

```
NSDateFormatter* rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];

NSDate* date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:yourString]; 

[aDateFormatter release];
```

more information is available on the [Apple Formatting Dates Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)
and you can also find more information on the RFC3339 date format (regarding the T and Z) [in this section of the RFC3339 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6)

Comment: actually the format is: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'". Thanks for the help

Comment: This is incorrect. You must either not quote the `Z` or your should specify the `timeZone` of the formatter to be GMT/UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The way to parse RFC 3339/ISO 8601 dates is as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Or, in macOS 10.12 and iOS 10:

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Then:

```
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Note, the `ZZZZZ` tells the formatter to use the time zone present in the string (where GMT+0 is represented as `Z`) when converting strings to `NSDate` objects. Likewise, by setting both the `dateFormat` and the `timeZone`, this formatter can also be used to convert `NSDate` objects back into strings like `2011-08-24T14:06:10Z`, doing the necessary time zone conversions. Bottom line, this formatter works both directions.

The use of the `locale` property is also best practice, as it ensures that the date will be properly interpreted regardless of the device's particular calendar (i.e. notably if it's not a Gregorian calendar). See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).